Relative homotopy equivalence despite not being a retract?
The following chain of implications, for a subspace $A$ of $X$, is well-known and easy:

($(X, A)\cong (Y, B)$ means that there exist $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f(A)\subseteq B$, $g(B)\subseteq A$, $g\circ f\simeq_A \mathrm{id}_X$ and $f\circ g\simeq_B\mathrm{id}_Y$.)
This naturally raises the question whether $(X, A)\cong (A, A)$ implies that $A$ is a retract of $X$. A proof or a counterexample?

Note that if $(X, A)\cong (A, A)$ via the inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$, then $A$ will be SDR and hence a retract.
